# Adding a fade out tabbed list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

[Our advert pages her](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/health-and-beauty/beauty-salons-and-spas/the-beauty-studio-brentwood-481.html)e use the following jscript for the tabs:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $('.tab:not(.aboutus)').hide();

    $('.tabs li').click(function(){
        var thisAd = $(this).parent().parent();
        $(thisAd).children('.tab').hide();
        $(thisAd).children('.'+$(this).attr('class').replace('tab','')).show();
        $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });


    if(window.location.hash) {
        if (window.location.hash == "#map") {
            $(".Advert").children('.tab').hide();
            $(".Advert").children('.map').show();
            $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');                                                    
            $('.maptab').addClass('active');
        }
        if (window.location.hash == "#voucher") {
            $(".Advert").children('.tab').hide();
            $(".Advert").children('.vouchers').show();
        }
    }   

});
```

And I'd like to incorporate a fade effect [like the example here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/community.html) which uses this js:

```
(function($) {

    $.organicTabs = function(el, options) {

        var base = this;
        base.$el = $(el);
        base.$nav = base.$el.find(".nav");

        base.init = function() {

            base.options = $.extend({},$.organicTabs.defaultOptions, options);

            // Accessible hiding fix
            $(".hide").css({
                "position": "relative",
                "top": 0,
                "left": 0,
                "display": "none"
            }); 

            base.$nav.delegate("li > a", "click", function() {

                // Figure out current list via CSS class
                var curList = base.$el.find("a.current").attr("href").substring(1),

                // List moving to
                    $newList = $(this),

                // Figure out ID of new list
                    listID = $newList.attr("href").substring(1),

                // Set outer wrapper height to (static) height of current inner list
                    $allListWrap = base.$el.find(".list-wrap"),
                    curListHeight = $allListWrap.height();
                $allListWrap.height(curListHeight);

                if ((listID != curList) && ( base.$el.find(":animated").length == 0)) {

                    // Fade out current list
                    base.$el.find("#"+curList).fadeOut(base.options.speed, function() {

                        // Fade in new list on callback
                        base.$el.find("#"+listID).fadeIn(base.options.speed);

                        // Adjust outer wrapper to fit new list snuggly
                        var newHeight = base.$el.find("#"+listID).height();
                        $allListWrap.animate({
                            height: newHeight
                        });

                        // Remove highlighting - Add to just-clicked tab
                        base.$el.find(".nav li a").removeClass("current");
                        $newList.addClass("current");

                    });

                }   

                // Don't behave like a regular link
                // Stop propegation and bubbling
                return false;
            });

        };
        base.init();
    };

    $.organicTabs.defaultOptions = {
        "speed": 300
    };

    $.fn.organicTabs = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            (new $.organicTabs(this, options));
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Update: These are the bits of code I thin I need to amend my code to work with, but could do with some help integrating it:

```
          // Fade out current list
            base.$el.find("#"+curList).fadeOut(base.options.speed, function() {

                // Fade in new list on callback
                base.$el.find("#"+listID).fadeIn(base.options.speed);
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the default [duration parameter](http://api.jquery.com/show/) of show() and hide():

```
.show('fast/normal/slow/[duration in ms]')
.hide('fast/normal/slow/[duration in ms]')
```

From comments:

you get a strange fading effect, because you have multiple container divs (with the grey border and all) which fade, while in the example [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/community.html) you have one container with a grey background and all the contents in it, then you fade just the contents.

Comment: Hehe no, read the docs pls ;). fast/normal/etc. are just different options which define how fast the fading effect will be, so with hide('fast') it will be hidden very fast and with hide('slow') it will fade away pretty slowly. Alternatively you can specify the fade duration yourself like .hide(300), which means that it fades out during 300 milliseconds.